# Wait for Date Field to Equal Today not triggering

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, 2016, timer-jobs

I have a workflow that is supposed to send reminders when a date field in the item becomes Today's date. For that reason I have the condition:

> Wait for Document Next Review Date to equal Today
>
> Then Do Something

The problem is that when the said date comes, the workflow does not continue, but rather keeps "waiting". Timer Service is running properly and the date formats are the same.

What would be the cause of this? Our SharePoint version is 2016, while my Designer is 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question but it might solve your issue.

My recommendation is:
Make "sleep till date {Document Next Review Date} " In the workflow and when it exits that Then Do Something

This is what im doing right now, i have multiple blocks competing in a parallel block, then one who sets the exit condition first exits.

[image: Workflow visual editor]

Answer (score 0):

the workflow does not generates until the item is edited, even if you have the wait or sleep condition it won`t trigger the workflow until you re-submit the action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Log to History list" action to log Today, which should be always the date that the workflow is triggered, and not a dynamic value,so, it always keeps "waiting...".

For your requirement, you can use a retention policy of Information Management Policy to trigger the workflow instead of using "Waiting for ...".

A blog for your reference:
[How to trigger a workflow on a timer basis: Information management policies](http://wardpeter.com/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-on-a-timer-basis-information-management-policies/)